# Is there an easy way to exclude nodes using Spark with Yarn?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

**Overview**
I don't really want queues or node labels.  I just want to specify that this spark application should run on 2 workers, choose them at will.  I can't seem to do this, so I have set up each node on its own node label and have made queues that limit access to some nodes.

**The Situation**
So let's say I have node labels a,b,c for nodes http://a.example:10000, http://b.example:10000, and http://c.example:10000.

I have queues: 1_q,2_q,3_q
1_q has **a** accessible
2_q has **a,b** accessible
3_q has **a,b,c** accessible

I would like to be able to use queue 1_q and have it run 100% of a's  resources
I would like to be able to use queue 2_q and have it run 100% of a and 100% of b
I would like to be able to use queue 3_q and have it run 100% of a and 100% of b and 100% of c

I have set node labels a,b,c as "exclusive=false" as well as trying "exclusive=true".
I was able to get things working with "exclusive=false" but it used more than the accessible nodes.  I tried "exclusive=true" but 3_q runs in the default partition with nothing there for resources so nothing gets run.

**There is a pyspark property already**
I really think all of this is overkill anyway.
There is a pyspark property:
`spark.yarn.exclude.nodes`
but it doesn't do anything in my experience.  I have tried:
 `conf.set("spark.yarn.exclude.nodes","a")`
as well as
 `conf.set("spark.yarn.exclude.nodes","a.example")`
But it doesn't exclude them, ie I can clearly see containers running on those nodes using yarn web ui for that application

it would be nice if I could just set a queue that has all the partitions available and then exclude them with that property.
or
it would be nice if a "node Label Expression" could include multiple labels.

Does this way of using yarn/spark/pyspark  even seem plausible ( exclude some nodes on a per application basis? )

Comment: I don't understand the point of exclude nodes on application basis and why you need that?
Also you could specify the number of executors that your application will use in the spark-submit parameters and only those number of executors your application will use.

Comment: Because I want to, should suffice.  I'm not asking for an alternative, there are plenty of those circling the internet.  Maybe an explanation of "spark.yarn.exclude.nodes" would be helpful.  Seems it should do what I want, yet it doesn't.  If I want to limit which nodes are processing stuff, it should be my choice, just like using slurm or some other scheduler.  limiting executors is completely circling around the issue.